# binding UImageView in cell to wrong row number with dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ios

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have `UITableView` with custom cells containing white image - when you press it becomes green (Customer put something in their basket).

```
    - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
        int volume = self.seats.count;
        return volume;
    }   
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        _currentSeat = [_seats objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }


   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSString *identifier = @"seatCell";
    //todo try fix bug with dequing indexes
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
   if (!cell) {
       cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                                      reuseIdentifier:identifier];
    }
    Seat *cur = [_seats objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _currentSeat = cur;
    UILabel* tr = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:51];
    tr.text = cur.rowNum;

    UILabel* tr2 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:52];
    tr2.text = cur.seatNum;

    NSArray* piecesOfPrice = [cur.price componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
    if (piecesOfPrice.count > 1) {
        cur.price = [piecesOfPrice objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    UILabel* tr3 = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:53];
    NSMutableString *prm = [cur.price mutableCopy];
    [prm appendString:@" p"];
    tr3.text = prm;

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleImageTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(addToBasketTapDetected:)];
    singleImageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    UIImageView* imv = (UIImageView*)[cell viewWithTag:54];
    [imv setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [imv addGestureRecognizer:singleImageTap];
    imv.tag = indexPath.row;

    return cell;
}
-(void)addToBasketTapDetected: (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender{
    NSLog(@"single Tap on imageview");
    UIImageView *theTappedImageView = (UIImageView *)sender.view;
    NSInteger tag = theTappedImageView.tag;
    Seat* seat = [_seats objectAtIndex:tag];
    NSMutableString *urlStr = [NSMutableString new];
    [ urlStr appendString:@"http://19-00.ru/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/1900-1900channel-Site/ru_RU/-/RUR/ViewStandardCatalog-AddProductToCart?SelectedGood=1@"];
    [urlStr appendString: seat.productRefID];
    NSString *u = [[urlStr mutableCopy]stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:u];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSString *ret = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Row number from sender: %d", tag);
    if ([ret containsString : seat.productRefID]){
        //Ticket_added
        NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rectangle_21_copy_5" ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *prodImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        [theTappedImageView setImage:prodImg];
    }
    else {
        //server error
    }
}
```

the ios duplicates recoloring the image in each row of same number in each section. So I get multiple products added to basket with 1 click which is incorrect. Method `numberOfRowsInSection` returns correct number of rows(50).
I tried to play around and found that method `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` returns correct row numbers(14 for ex). But I need to click on image, not on row.
And method `cellForRowAtIndexPath` - is the single place where I can bind image to cell but it plays wrong with row/section number. How to handle this?

Comment: You write "ios duplicates recoloring the image in each row of same number in each section". Do you actually have multiple sections? Your code doesn't indicate that you do.

Answer (score 1):

In the method `addToBasketTapDetected` you are not showing us how you actually find `theTappedImageView` and I suspect that this is what goes wrong.

But in any case, I would not do it in the table view controller at all, but rather subclass the `UIViewCell` and handle the tap in there because you would be sure you have the correct cell.

Also, I wouldn't use an `UIImageView` either but an `UIButton` where you configure two states: `UIControlStateNormal` and `UIControlSelected`, and when the button has been tapped you set it to `button.selected = YES` (and `NO` if you tap again). This would give you a toggle button.

Comment: Most importantly you need to record the selection into your data model. You cannot rely on the cell itself recording the state as cells will be reused.

Comment: Good point @Paulw11. For me this is one of those things that go without saying, but sometimes they need to be said :)

Comment: In my experience that is the most common problem people have when they ask "my cells are doing weird things" questions

Comment: True. That was my first assumption here as well until I saw that he got selection in the same row of every section, which indicated a different problem.

Comment: Nope, same problem they don't update their model and they don't check the model/update the image in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`  But you are also right that the gesture recogniser is pretty awful

Comment: Perhaps you are correct. It's just that when it is an reuse issue it's usually manifested "randomly". "The same row of each section" seems more specific. Without seeing the rest of his code we cannot know for sure.

Comment: Please, give any relevant link or code from where I could practice the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

```
@interface TableViewController () <TableViewCellDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedIndexPathes;
@end

@implementation TableViewController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *TableViewCellIdentifier = @"TableViewCellIdentifier";
    TableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:TableViewCellIdentifier];

    cell.imageView.image = [self.selectedIndexPathes containsObject:indexPath] ?
        [UIImage imageNamed:@"selected_image"] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"unselected_image"];
    return cell;
}

#pragma mark - TableViewCellDelegate methods

- (void)tableViewCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell didSelectImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if (![self.selectedIndexPathes containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.selectedIndexPathes addObject:indexPath];
    }
}

@end

@protocol TableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>
- (void)tableViewCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell didSelectImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView;
@end

@interface TableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<TableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@end

@interface TableViewCell()
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *addToBasketImageView;
@end

@implementation TableViewCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleImageTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:
                                              self action:@selector(addToBasketTapDetected:)];
    singleImageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.addToBasketImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleImageTap];
}

- (void)addToBasketTapDetected: (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self.delegate tableViewCell:self didSelectImageView:self.addToBasketImageView];
}
```

Do you understand what I doing here?

Comment: Yes, in general. The only thing remains uncovered for me - how to bind cell.imageView.image to storyboard? If I dont use nib files. What method should I override then? Or alternatively, how create nib file for table cell ?

Comment: As I see in your code - you use UITableViewCell, so you can easily do like this: `[self.imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleImageTap];`. In this case you don't need to bind anything.
But if you want to bind - then use `IBOutlet`

Comment: OK with that. Next question is why do I need awakeFromNib - and if I dont - I can simply erase it and append recognizer to image in cellForRowAtIndexPath? Or where should I better do it? Could you edit please to show?

Comment: awakeFromNib is a good place for do that. This method will be called when cell is appear. UIViewController should not be responsible for setting  cell recognizers. Look like UIButton work. Do you set button recognizer in controller?