# TableViewCellDelegate isnt being called

Tags: ios, uitableview, protocols

I am trying to add item to basket in this files. I have custom table cell and linked it with IBOutlets in storyboard. Somehow debugger reaches the delegate method inside deletegating object, but doesnt go further to TableVC, where this method is conformed, and no logs are seen.

```
//  SeatTableViewCell.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SeatTableViewCellDelegate.h"

@interface SeatTableViewCell : UITableViewCell
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SeatTableViewCellDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *rowLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *seatLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UILabel *priceLabel;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIImageView *addToBasketImageView;
@end

//  SeatTableViewCell.m
#import "SeatTableViewCell.h"
@implementation SeatTableViewCell
@synthesize rowLabel, seatLabel, priceLabel, addToBasketImageView;
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleImageTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:
                                              self action:@selector(addToBasketTapDetected:)];
    singleImageTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
    [self.addToBasketImageView addGestureRecognizer:singleImageTap];
}

- (void)addToBasketTapDetected: (UIGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    //HERE the debugger stops, after step into nothing happens
    [self.delegate tableViewCell:self didSelectImageView:self.addToBasketImageView];
}
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
@end
//  SeatTableViewCellDelegate.h
@protocol SeatTableViewCellDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)tableViewCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell didSelectImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView;

@end

//  ChooseSeatTableViewController.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "SeatGroup.h"
#import "SeatTableViewCellDelegate.h"
@interface ChooseSeatTableViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, SeatTableViewCellDelegate>
- (IBAction)onBackPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)OnChooseSectorClicked:(id)sender;
-(void)reloadData:(SeatGroup *)selectedSeatGroup;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) SeatGroup *seatGroup;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString* perfUUID;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *tableHeightConstraint;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray* seats;
@end

//  ChooseSeatTableViewController.m
#import "ChooseSeatTableViewController.h" 
#import "ConcertDescriptionViewController.h"
#import "SeatTableViewCell.h"    
@interface ChooseSeatTableViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *selectedIndexPathes;
@property (strong) Seat*  currentSeat;
@end

@implementation ChooseSeatTableViewController

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    int volume = self.seats.count;
    return volume;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    _currentSeat = [_seats objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSString *identifier = @"seatCell";
    //todo try fix bug with dequing indexes
   SeatTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Seat *cur = [_seats objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _currentSeat = cur;
    cell.rowLabel.text = cur.rowNum;
    cell.seatLabel.text = cur.seatNum;
    NSArray* piecesOfPrice = [cur.price componentsSeparatedByString: @","];
    if (piecesOfPrice.count > 1) {
        cur.price = [piecesOfPrice objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    NSMutableString *prm = [cur.price mutableCopy];
    [prm appendString:@" p"];
    cell.priceLabel.text = prm;

        [cell.addToBasketImageView setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];

    if ([self.selectedIndexPathes containsObject:indexPath]) {
        //set basket selected
        NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rectangle_21_copy_5" ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *priceBckgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        cell.addToBasketImageView.image = priceBckgImg;
    } else {
        //set basket unselected
        NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rectangle_21_copy_6" ofType:@"png"];
        UIImage *priceBckgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
        cell.addToBasketImageView.image = priceBckgImg;
    }

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableViewCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell didSelectImageView:(UIImageView *)imageView {
    //HERE the debugger doesnt reach
    NSLog(@"Hi, debugger in didSelectImageView");
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if (![self.selectedIndexPathes containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [self.selectedIndexPathes addObject:indexPath];
    }
    NSString *thePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"rectangle_21_copy_5" ofType:@"png"];
    UIImage *priceBckgImg = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:thePath];
    [imageView setImage:priceBckgImg];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

..
Why my protocol isn being called?

Comment: make sure your delegate is not nil

Comment: in the debugger I can see 0, but not nil _delegate id 0x0 0x00000000

Comment: which means you dont have an object. THis is very basic question. It's not encouraged to ask such questions here.

Comment: I supposed it would be synthesized as a property.  I adopted this code from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37161104/binding-uimageview-in-cell-to-wrong-row-number-with-dequeuereusablecellwithident

Answer (score 1):

You have to set your view controller as delegate:

```
    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
             NSString *identifier = @"seatCell";
             SeatTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
             cell.delegate = self;
             ....
     }
```

Answer (score 1):

AlexInspired,

The only statement missing is in cellForRowAtIndexPath :)

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSString *identifier = @"seatCell";
    //todo try fix bug with dequing indexes
   SeatTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Seat *cur = [_seats objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    _currentSeat = cur;
    cell.rowLabel.text = cur.rowNum;
    cell.seatLabel.text = cur.seatNum;
    cell.delegate = self;
    ....
    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't set delegate for tableview cell.

Set delegate and enjoy :) your problem is solved.

```
cell.delegate = self
```

Answer (score 1):

you forget to set delegate to self. so in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` set delegate to self like,

```
   - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        NSString *identifier = @"seatCell";
//todo try fix bug with dequing indexes
  SeatTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

         cell.delegate = self;

 }
```

by this you are assigning current class object to cell class so you can able to call current class method from cell class.

:)

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   NSString *identifier = @"seatCell";
    //todo try fix bug with dequing indexes
   SeatTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.delegate=self;
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

write following code in CellforRowAtIndexPath method it will help for you

```
NSString *cellDdentifier = @"seatCell";
SeatTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.delegate = self
```